# redirecting window is not working properly in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, spservices

i am trying to develop a html, after submitting that page i want to redirect to another page using javascript window.location.href tag but it is not working properly, it is redirecting to the same page(or reloading)
thanks..

```
function submit(){
            $().SPServices({
                operation: "UpdateListItems",
                async: true,  
                batchCmd: "New",
                listName: "list",
                valuepairs: [["ReportTitle",$('#txtTitle').val()],
                ["VerticalL1",$('#ddlL1 option:selected').text()],
                ["VerticalL2",$('#ddlL2 option:selected').text()],
                ["ReasonForSuggestingTitle",$('#txtReason').val()]],
                completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                    if (Status == 'success' && $(xData.responseXML).find('ErrorCode').text() == '0x00000000') {
                        alert('Thank you for responding to our survey!'); 
                        var url ="www.stackoverflow.com";
                        window.location.href= url;
                    }
                }

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try url with **http://**

```
 var url ="http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```